# Can I add a VPN client to my OpenVPN server so my users don't browse on Internet with my server IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, vpn-client

I currently have an OpenVPN server running on a machine. My clients are able to connect to this VPN in order to access our internal apps and have the ability to browse internet.

I don't want my VPN users to browse with my server public IP address (from the websites point of vue).

So, is there a way and what is the best way to install an *external* VPN in order that the HTTP queries of my VPN users don't use my public server IP address ?

OS : Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)

Thank you

Comment: in fact, either you use a second server or ip as exit point or dont allow internet or dont use the default route, so that the users are not forced to use your vpn for what reason ever and maybe block 80/443 for any non lan targets

Comment: You can use a VPN tunnel as the default route for traffics from / clients of another one (with `ip rule` and an extra route table).

Comment: By default OpenVPN does not direct your clients traffic out: See https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#redirect